# Problem while reloading config using sv hup SIGHUP signal

Tags: c++, signals

I have a service written in c++ which is listening at a certain port. I want to reload the config file using sudo sv hup service_name SIGHUP signal. But the service gets restarted. The service gets restarted only when the socket is closed or blocked. Does the SIGHUP signal block the listening port?

Answer (score 0):

`SIGHUP` is sent to your process when it tries to write into a socket or pipe that has been closed on the other side. This is why people normally block `SIGHUP` signal in networking applications. (Also, when a session leader process terminates it sends `SIGHUP` to all child processes in its process group.)

If you do not block `SIGHUP` because you want to handle it, make sure your application passes `MSG_NOSIGNAL` into all `send` calls, so that it does not generate `SIGHUP`. Otherwise you won't be able to tell what caused that `SIGHUP` - `send` of `pkill -SIGHUP my_app`.

Since `SIGHUP` has multiple uses you may like to use another signal, like `SIGUSR1`, to instruct your application to reload the config. Nothing else sends this signal. Or have your application open a TCP or UNIX socket to which you can send commands to your application.